# Loading multiple files of particular directory and find and replace function in all files

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I am trying to develop a project in which  i am performing a sequence of processes. I want to load all the files of particular type (*.xhtml) from a directory . The files should open in tabs. I want to search for a particular tag and replace with another tag in all the files that is find and replace functionality. How to accommodate this.

Comment: It is hard to say (at least for me) what you're trying to do. Could you please, clarify the question?

Comment: Yeah. What project type is it? WinForms, WPF, or are you doing a CMS?

Comment: It is a windows forms application

Answer (score 2):

So what's the problem?

1. Search files:

   `var files = DirectoryInfo.GetFiles("*.xhtml", SearchOption.AllDirectories)`
2. Load in tabs. Not a big pro in windows forms but I think it's something like add new tab control to some tabs container per each found file.
3. See Oybek's answer regarding last point!

Hope it helped.

Comment: This is a really good answer except the point 3. [Never ever never ever never ever use RegEx for XML/HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Answer (score 1):

Well as far as the IO is concerned it is pretty straightforward, read directory, iterate over files and read content.

The following code snippet replaces the node of the xml.

```
var data = @"<foo>
    <items>
        <itemToReplace>
            <itemContent />
        </itemToReplace>
    </items>
</foo>";
        // Load your document
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(data);
        // Get the root
        var root = doc.Element("items");
        // Get all tags that you want to replace
        var repls = doc.Descendants("itemToReplace").ToList();
        // Iterate over
        foreach (var item in repls) {
            // prepare a new element as a replacement for your target.
            // Content will be the same as the content of the element being replaced.
            var newElement = new XElement("newElement", item.DescendantNodes());
            // add the element right after the tag to be replaced
            item.AddAfterSelf(newElement);
            // finally remove the tag.
            item.Remove();
        }
        MessageBox.Show(doc.ToString());
```

`itemToReplace` is replaced by `newElement`. As you say XHTML I suppose that there is a some sort of well formed XML/HTML that can be parsed via linq2xml. Cheers.